# JavaScript regex and replace like PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, javascript

I have following code in php:

```
    $link ='mylink';
    $description = '<p><a href="http://news.yahoo.com/obama-plans-full-court-press-sway-congress-syria-004845350.html"><img src="http://l3.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/hmYETKsJS2CXBsG7oO125w--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2013-09-07T045234Z_3_CBRE9851BPL00_RTROPTP_2_RUSSIA-G20.JPG"></a>By Roberta Rampton and Susan Cornwell WASHINGTON (Reuters) - ...</p>';
    $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
    $new_des = preg_replace($pattern,"?url=".$link,$description);
```

How can I do that in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript does not support look-behind assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern = /(href=["'])[^"']+(?=["'])/
new_des = description.replace(pattern, "$1?url=" + link)
```

JS doesn't support lookbehinds, therefore you'll have to capture the first group and insert it back when replacing using `$1`.